# Is WebProtocolException included in .net 4.0?

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, rest

The WCF starter kit has WebProtocolException to throw exceptions in WCF. Is this included in .net 4.0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please read the article *[Introducing WCF WebHttp Services in .NET 4](https://web.archive.org/web/20111105112903/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/01/06/introducing-wcf-webhttp-services-in-net-4.aspx)* which describes how WCF in .NET Framework 4 now includes those features like automatic help page for WCF Web HTTP service and `WebFaultException` exceptions (compare with `WebProtocolException` from the [*WCF REST Starter Kit* for WCF 3.5 from CodePlex](https://web.archive.org/web/20130218162304/http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/24644)).

The server side code examples use only types in `System.ServiceModel.Web.dll` and **not** the `Microsoft.ServiceModel.Web.dll` file from the *WCF REST Starter Kit*).

For client-side code you can continue to use *Microsoft.Http.dll* and *Microsoft.Http.Extensions.dll* from the WCF 3.5 *[WCF REST Starter Kit Preview 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20130218162304/http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/24644)*.

Another good article is *[A Developer's Introduction to Windows Communication Foundation 4](https://web.archive.org/web/20230611164811/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ee354381(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)*

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not a native class in .net 4.0