# How do I deal with different requests that map to the same response?

Tags: http, caching

I'm designing a Web service. The request is idempotent, so I chose the `GET` method. The response is relatively expensive to calculate and not small, so I want to get caching (on the protocol level) right. (Don't worry about memoisation at my part, I have that already covered; my question here is actually also paying attention to the Web as a whole.)

There's only one mandatory parameter and a number of optional parameter with default values if missing. For example, the following two map to the same representation of the response. (If this is a dumb way to go about it the interface, propose something better.)

```
GET /service?mandatory_parameter=some_data HTTP/1.1
GET /service?mandatory_parameter=some_data;optional_parameter=default1;another_optional_parameter=default2;yet_another_optional_parameter=default3 HTTP/1.1
```

However, I imagine clients do not know this and would treat them separate and therefore waste cache storage. What should I do to avoid violating the [golden rule of caching](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#TIPS)?

1. Make up a canonical form, document it (e.g. all parameters are required after all and need to be sorted in a specific order) and return a [client error](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4) unless the required form is met?
2. Instead of an error, redirect permanently to the canonical form of a request?
3. Or is it enough to not mind how the request looks like, and just respond with the same `ETag` for same responses?

Comment: Consensus seems to be to use 2., I'll go this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, don't use semicolons as a delimiter in a query string.  You should be using `?` to begin a query string and `&` to delimit variable/value pairs.  [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) doesn't explicitly say you have to use `&`, but the vast majority of existing code uses this delimiter because of the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` precedent.

Second, you're right, in that parameters in a query string result in a different URI, and thus, as far as caches are concerned, a different resource.  Assuming you want optimal caching performance, if you know that an optional parameter has been specified, and its inclusion is unnecessary and does not affect the representation that will be transmitted, you should be making a redirect to a canonical representation that omits the parameter.  (i.e., An optional parameter is given with a value that is set to the default value.  For example, if you have `http://example.com:80/`, you can normalize to `http://example.com/` because `80` is the default value for the port with HTTP.  You can do the same for query parameters since you control the URI space.)  If you have parameters included (optional or otherwise) that appear in an order other than the canonical order, you should redirect for that too.  A 301 redirect would be preferred if you know that the relationship between URIs will be stable.  Otherwise, do a 302/307 redirect as appropriate.  I would recommend defining your canonical form the same way that [OAuth](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-3.4.1.3.2) does: Sort each parameter alphabetically, first by key, then by value.  Other normalization operations will also help out here.  RFC 3986 has an entire section on [URI normalization](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-6) that will be relevant to you.  This technique will really only work for GET, and redirects on PUT/POST/DELETE are not generally recommended.

Third, ETags are great, and they provide a huge performance improvement if implemented well by both the client and server.  However, it's unfortunately rare for both sides to do it right.  Ditto for Last-Modified.  You should pursue these, because the CPU and bandwidth savings are significant when it works, but they are not sufficient on their own.  Other headers like Cache-Control are also frequently necessary.  It's worth familiarizing yourself with [Section 13 of RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-13) if you're planning on going into great detail on this stuff.

Finally, a word of warning — there is an issue with these redirects you need to be aware of:  Clients trying to access your resources may frequently be redirected to other locations.  This introduces overhead that only gives you an overall savings if the clients make subsequent requests against the same resource, maintaining state to avoid the subsequent redirect.  Unless you've open-sourced a reference client implementation that takes advantage of your caching optimizations, you may never benefit from these tweaks.

Comment: I reject `&` because of [HTML4 §B.2.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.2.2). +1 for pointing out canonicalisation from OAuth, I'll steal this. I don't see any problem with respect to needing a reference implementation; it's just HTTP after all. As another answer said, permanent redirects are both cheap and cachable.

Comment: That recommendation would only ever apply in the case where your URIs would appear directly within HTML or XML.  However, even in those cases, if you're not already escaping those URIs before inserting them into the content, you're doing it wrong.  The recommendation in this specification is irrelevant to everything but hand-coded output.

Comment: On the subject of reference implementations, I think you may be putting too much faith in the people who will be using your API.  If it works without setting up caching, people won't set up caching.

Answer (score 1):

I would pick option (2) in your list - I would make the request RESTful, rather than RPC like.

I.e. in this case, if you make all of the parameters parts of the request path:

/service/mandatory_parameter/some_data/optional_parameter/default1/another_optional_parameter/default2/yet_another_optional_parameter/default3

In the case where not all of the optional parameters are specified, return a 301 (Permanent redirect) to the full resource name with the defaults filled in. This will (or should) be cached by clients and web caches appropriately, and even if it gets to your backend then making the 301 should be very cheap for you.

At which point, you have one canonical form for the URI, and caching will work as normal/expected.

This does mean that every combination of parameters will be cached separately (as a 301), however that's fine really as the non-canonical requests will have an independent cache policy to the full request and clients which are worried about the extra round trip can fill in all the parameters themselves.

Your option (3) won't work as you expect - each form will be cached independently as they're different URIs.

It should also be noted that a lot of downstream caches / software won't cache your response **at all** due to the query parameters, which is why I suggest turning it into a 'proper' resource..

Comment: The URI you've suggested is not RESTful, and using query parameters does not make a URI "RPC-like".  I strongly recommend against actually doing this if you really have this many parameters.  This is cargo-culting at best.  Please read Roy Fielding's dissertation for the actual definition of the REST architectural style.

Comment: t0m, Bob A. is right. I don't know what gave you the idea that my design violates the criteria of the architectural style, but it is conformant as it is. You as the maintainer of REST for Catalyst should recognise this. The lots of slashes imply a hierarchy where there isn't one; namely the parameters are on equal footing.

Comment: You can't just change URL structure and make a service RESTful, what you suggest is not RESTful.

Answer (score 0):

First it's a good thing you choice GET since other methods don't have as good caching support. As far as I know browsers do cache URIs with respect to the parameters so I don't think It's a good idea to use a canonical form.
One thing that you don't state here is how this service is going to be used. If those requests are made from a browser (and it looks to me that those are probably issued from a script) requests will probably look the same even if they are asked for more than once. So make sure that whatever generate the URI end up with the same URI for equal input data (remove default parameters or always include them).
When it comes to the ETag I recommend you to have this, though I would like to clarify how it works; You get the request, you process all your "expensive calculations" and then if there were a If-None-Match header with the same hash (ETag) as your processed response you may return 304 Not-Modified. So ETag is used to avoid transmitting the response if the client already have it. (Sure you may implement caching on server-side, but this is better to do based on input parameters).
To further improve cache hits on client side you may want to set proper caching headers in you response.

Comment: This answer gives no new insights.

Comment: When it was the second answer posted it did.

Answer (score 0):

I asked almost the same question for me some month ago. My answer I describe on an example of my realization.

On the server side I have WFC service which receive requests in one of the following forms

```
GET /Service/RequestedData?param1=data1&param2=data2…
GET /Service/RequestedData/IdOfData?param1=data1&param2=data2…
PUT /Service/RequestedData/IdOfData // with param1=data1&param2=data2… in body
POST /Service/RequestedData/IdOfData // with param1=data1&param2=data2… in body
DELETE /Service/RequestedData/IdOfData
```

So requests are in REST for, but `GET` requests have some optional parameters. Especially this part is a port of your interest.

Because WFC support a URL templates, the prototype of functions which reply to a client request looks like

```
[WebGet (UriTemplate = "RequestedData?param1={myParam1}&param2={myParam2}",
         ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
[OperationContract]
MyResult GetData (string myParam1, int myParam2);
```

All requests like

```
GET /Service/RequestedData?param1=&param2=data2
GET /Service/RequestedData?param2=data2&param1=
GET /Service/RequestedData?param2=data2
```

will be mapped to the same call from the side of my WCF service. So I have one problem less.

Now at the beginning of implementation of every method which response to HTTP `GET` request I set in the HTTP header "*Cache-Control: max-age=0*". It means that client **always** try to verify client browser cache and no `ajax` requests will be not easy responded from the local cache like it can do Internet Explorer.

Next I calculate always an `ETag` based on my data. The exact algorithm is a subject of separate discussion, but important is, that in all responses to HTTP `GET` requests exist `ETag` in the HTTP header.

So clients every time verify his local cache and send GET request to server. They send the `ETag`, which come from its local cache, inside of "`If-None-Match`" HTTP header. Server computes the `ETag` which has data, which will be sending back to this GET request. It `ETag` of data is the same as in the client request server send back response with empty body and the code "`304 Not Modified`" back. In this case browser gives data from the local cache.

If the same client from a unknown reason create a new version of URL request, which will be interpret from the web browser as a **new** URL, then web browser will not find old server response in the local cache and send one more time the same request to the server. Is it a real problem? The server send the data one more time. If you have a server side caching you can makes a little more optimization. In the most cases, the URL of GET requests will be produced by a client side JavaScript so you will be no time have such situation.

Calculation of `ETag` and setting of "`Cache-Control: max-age=0`" and `Etag` header as well as setting "`304 Not Modified`" code should do WFC service, but it is very easy.

The most important is that my implementation of `ETag` calculation is not as expansive as getting the whole data from the database server and calculation MD5 cache from there. I use permanently `rowversion` data type in every row of data in the SQL Server database. This `rowversion` is nothing other as a counter of changes in the database. If one change a row of data `rowversion` value in the corresponding row will be incremented. So if one makes `SELECT` statement from maximum value of `rowversion` value, and this value is not changed comparing with the previous requests, one can be sure that the data were not changed in the time period. The algorithm of calculation of `ETa`g should be only sensitive to deleting of data from the table. But it is also a solved problem. A little more about this you can read in [Concurrency handling of Sql transactrion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658443/concurrency-handling/2663654#2663654).

I don’t want suggest my `ETag` calculation as a best choice, I want only say, that calculation of `ETag` can be much cheaper as calculation MD5 from the whole data.

In case of errors Server throws an exception which will be mapped to a HTTP code, which I define in the throw statement. As a body WFC sends a standard JSON object `{"description":"My error text"}`. A custom error object is also possible (see [Is WebProtocolException included in .net 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891119/is-webprotocolexception-included-in-net-4-0/2633677#2633677)). On the client side I use jQuery and in the corresponding `jQuery.ajax` inside of error event handler the error message will be decoded and displayed to the user.

So my recommendation: usage of `ETag` together with "`Cache-Control: max-age=0`" for all HTTP `GET` requests. For all other requests I’ll recommend you implement *RESTfull* service. For the error implementation you should look at the most native way which is supported by the software used for server and client implementation and use this.

**UPDATED**: To clear the URL structure I should add following. In my service the main part like `GET /Service/RequestedData/IdOfData` describes data objects requested. Parameters `param1=data1&param2=data2` corresponds mostly the information about *sorting*, *paging* and *filtering* of data. I use active jqGrid plugin for jQuery and if the end-user scroll in the grid to the next page, click on the column header (sorting of data) or if he set a filter with respect of searching feature, all these follows to different optional parameters appended the main URL.

Comment: By all means share your findings about Web service, but do it on your own blog. You ask: »Is it a real problem?« Yes, it is, this is why I asked this specific question! -1 for not paying attention to it.

Comment: Sorry if my answer is too long and looks like a blog for you. I want only helps you and so give not only short answer, but the explain my answer on an example. The short answers to your questions are: 1) canonical form is not needed If client request will be produced by a client software
2) no redirect in case of error, display an additional div with error message instead
3) use Etags, but a good one and not mind how the request looks like

Comment: If my answer don't helps you and you think, that it's my blog, I can delete my answer. I wait from you a short reply.